# Can SharePoint 2016 crawler index JavaScript driven pages?

Tags: javascript, search, enterprise-search, 2016

We have pages that are heavily driven by JavaScript and need to get them into the search results. Is this be possible?

Comment: Get what into the index? Do you dynamically render content from other places on load etc?

Comment: The content is mostly coming from SharePoint lists. I display it on the page using the REST API and ajax. I want to index these pages so that they will show up in the search results.